# ValueError while trying to convert pandas dataframe into dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to convert pandas dataframe into dask dataframe. Here is how my dataframe looks like, it only consists of file names and vectors

```
    file_names  \
    0  C:\Users\pilot_project\pilot_2/...   
    1  C:\Users\pilot_project\pilot_2/...   
    2  C:\Users\pilot_project\pilot_2/...   
    3  C:\Users\pilot_project\pilot_2/...   
    4  C:\Users\Yilmaz\Desktop\pilot_project\pilot_2/... 
      vectors  
    0  [0.011174, 0.011548, 0.011642, 0.000159, 2.3e-...  
    1  [0.003017, 0.003247, 0.003309, 9e-06, 6e-06, 8...  
    2  [0.008307, 0.008461, 0.008461, 0.0, 0.0, 2.8e-...  
    3  [0.007146, 0.007241, 0.007261, 0.000392, 2.4e-...  
    4  [0.007226, 0.007281, 0.007336, 9.9e-05, 1.9e-0...
```

Here is the simple code

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_pickle('output.p')
df1['vectors'] = df1['vectors'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x)) # This line didn't solve my problem
df = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=8)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: They have same size. They actually represent the same object and 
I will need them as a whole later on. My dataset is huge, actually I am trying to solve my issue with memory

Comment: I think it is possible

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Is it a Pandas problem or a Dask.dataframe problem?

Comment: I think it is a dask problem

Comment: You could confirm that by saying which line causes the error and providing a stack trace.

Comment: I think it is because I tried to save a list to dask array.  I gave up on dask solution, now looking for alternatives. I am a graduate student too btw :)